# How to put where in linq select statement for search bar

Tags: asp.net, linq, search

I have this code which joins 3 tables and binds the result in a gridview, i have a search bar and if the keyboard is contained in contacto.nombre then i want to add the object to the list.
I read i have to use contains.

```
public void SearchButtonClick(String keyword){
    using (ProfesionalesEmpresasEntities bd = new ProfesionalesEmpresasEntities())
    {
        var resultado = (from contacto in bd.Contactos
            join departamento in bd.DEPARTAMENTOS on contacto.id_departamento equals departamento.Id_dpto
            join localidad in bd.LOCALIDADES on contacto.id_localidad equals localidad.Id_Localidad
            join profesion in bd.Profesiones on contacto.id_profesion equals profesion.id_Profesion
            select new
            {
                Nombre = contacto.nombre,
                Apellido = contacto.apellido,
                Direccion = contacto.direccion,
                Empresa = contacto.empresa,
                Mail = contacto.mail
            }).ToList();

        grdContactos.DataSource = resultado;
        grdContactos.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SearchButtonClick(String keyword){
    using (ProfesionalesEmpresasEntities bd = new ProfesionalesEmpresasEntities())
    {
        var resultado = (from contacto in bd.Contactos
            join departamento in bd.DEPARTAMENTOS on contacto.id_departamento equals departamento.Id_dpto
            join localidad in bd.LOCALIDADES on contacto.id_localidad equals localidad.Id_Localidad
            join profesion in bd.Profesiones on contacto.id_profesion equals profesion.id_Profesion
            select new
            {
                Nombre = contacto.nombre,
                Apellido = contacto.apellido,
                Direccion = contacto.direccion,
                Empresa = contacto.empresa,
                Mail = contacto.mail
            })
            .Where(x=>x.Direccion.Contains(keyword))
            .ToList();

        grdContactos.DataSource = resultado;
        grdContactos.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is another way using the query syntax, but I'm afraid I don't know it, as I don't ever use the query syntax.  Most likely something like `where contacto.direccion.Contains(keyword)` placed right before `select new`